# MySQL: Select last X rows and then specific rows afterwards

Tags: mysql, sql

He is a tricky query that I can't seem to figure out unless I use PHP - which I want to avoid at any cost. So here is what I am trying to do...

I have a table named `invoices`. This table has a field called `paid`. This field is ticked after an invoice has been considered paid. Now, I have a page called `Latest Invoices` that shows a giant list of the first 100 invoices (paid & unpaid).

```
SELECT * FROM invoices ORDER BY id DESC, id LIMIT 100
```

Obviously works great. However, I want to adjust this statement by adding a condition that will also include any invoices that **ARE NOT** paid following the last 100 invoices.

So in other words:
- The first 100 invoices will show PAID/UNPAID
- And then any unpaid invoices will be afterwards (no limit)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to identify the first 100 invoices.  Here is a way of doing that by using a `join`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM invoices i left outer join
     (select i.*
      from invoices i
      order by id desc
      limit 100
     ) i100
     on i.id = i100.id
WHERE i100.id is not null or i.paid = 0
ORDER BY id desc;
```

The `order by` just uses `id`.  This will put the first 100 at the top.  The rest of the not-paid will follow those in inverse `id` order.